# Equal sign in Makefile target

Tags: makefile

Is there a good way to have equal signs in the target name of a Makefile?

If I write a Makefile like

```
test=file:
    touch test=file
```

I get

```
Makefile:2: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.
```

The only way I've found to get around that is to do

```
NAME = test=file

$(NAME):
    touch test=file
```

which works, but it would be a bit cumbersome to define a variable for every filename. Is there a better way to do this, by quoting/escaping the `=` directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way than using a variable to hide the `=`.  Of course you don't have to put the entire filename in the variable you can just use:

```
EQ = =
test$(EQ)file: ; touch $@
```

Or, if you put it into a single-letter variable you don't need the `()`:

```
E = =
test$Efile: ; touch $@
```

if you prefer.